# Error while connecting to db2

Tags: db2

While trying to connect to db2 , I am getting the following error

```
Connection failed: db2 sql error: sqlcode=-1060,sqlstate=08004
```

I tried to do a lookup on

> http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n514.htm

but don't see any meaning of the error message pertaining to this sqlcode. Please suggest on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is the wrong sqlcode you are looking up. And you don't find the sqlcode 1060 there, probably because your database is not version 9.1 or does not run on z/OS ???

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct error:

> SQL1060N  User "" does not have the CONNECT
>   privilege.
>
> Explanation:
>
> The specified authorization ID does not have the CONNECT privilege to
>   access the database. The CONNECT privilege must be granted before the
>   user can connect to a database. This error is also returned when a
>   switch user request is made with a user ID allowed on the trusted
>   connection but that user ID does not hold CONNECT privilege on the
>   database. The connection is put in an unconnected state.
>
> Federated system users: This situation can also be detected by the
>   data source
>
> The command cannot be processed.
>
> User response:
>
> Contact the system administrator or database administrator for the
>   database and request a GRANT CONNECT for the authorization ID.
>   Resubmit the command.
>
> If this error is returned as a result of a switch user request, then
>   until a switch user request with a valid user ID is made (the user ID
>   that established the trusted connection or a user ID allowed on the
>   trusted connection), if any SQL statement is issued, an error is
>   returned (SQLSTATE 08003). The connection remains trusted when it is
>   taken out of the unconnected state.
>
> Federated system users: if necessary isolate the problem to the data
>   source that rejected the request (see the Troubleshooting Guide for
>   procedures to follow to identify the data source that failed) and
>   ensure that correct privileges have been granted for that data source.
>   Some data sources might use a different name than the CONNECT
>   privilege for the privilege required to connect to a database.
>
> sqlcode: -1060
>
> sqlstate: 08004